# I want to capture the starting and end point of all the series in multigraph and show it in multiple tables in case of multiple MeasureXY events

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a MultiGraph i.e a graph with multiple series. What I want to do is use MeasureXY(stockTools GUI Button) to highlight a particular area in my graph and then display the starting and end point of all the series in that highlighted area in a separate table inside my widget. I am able to achieve this in case of single measuremnet using MeasureXY , but I want to create separate tables in case if user decides ro do multiple measurement in graph. What I am wondering is how will I treat every shaded portion individually because I will have to update thier corresponding tables. Any way I can identify them uniquely? Please see the code below.

```
    navigation: {
  bindings: {
      measureX: {
          end: function() {
              //gets triggered when the measure event ends
          }
      }
  },
  annotationsOptions: {
      events: {
          afterUpdate(e) {
            //gets triggered when the measure event updates.
          },
          remove(e, annotation) {
             // gets triggered when the clicked on the remove icon
          },
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any one from HighCharts team,, Can you answer this?

Comment: Hi @Nishit, measurements are stored as annotations in `chart.annotations` array and you can refer, for example to updated specific measure by `this` in the event callback. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ycmxg5w0/